# convert text to dataframe by specific pattern in R

Tags: r

I have text like this:

```
text <- "Jeon Bo-ram (born March 22, 1986):She, better known mononymously as Boram, is a South Korean singer and actress. She is best known as a member of the South Korean girl group T-ara. Taylor Alison Swift (born December 13, 1989): She is an American singer-songwriter. One of the leading contemporary recording artists, she is known for narrative songs about her personal life, which have received widespread media coverage. Nickolas Gene Carter (born January 28, 1980): He is an American musician and actor. He is best known as a member of the pop group the Backstreet Boys. As of 2015, Carter has released three solo albums, Now or Never, I'm Taking Off and All American during breaks between Backstreet Boys schedules, and a collaboration with Jordan Knight titled Nick & Knight. He has made occasional television appearances and starred in his own reality shows, House of Carters and I (Heart) Nick Carter. He gained fame in the mid 1990s and early 2000s as a teen idol. He is also the older brother of singer Aaron Carter and the late Leslie Carter. Clyde Jackson Browne (born October 9, 1948): He is an American singer-songwriter, and musician who has sold over 18 million albums in the United States. Coming to prominence in the 1970s, Browne has written and recorded songs such as These Days, The Pretender, Running on Empty, Lawyers in Love, Doctor My Eyes, Take It Easy, and  For a Rocker. In 2004, he was inducted into the Rock and Roll Hall of Fame in Cleveland, Ohio, and given an honorary doctorate of music by Occidental College in Los Angeles, California."
```

Any suggestions to get something like this:

```
name                      born                         detail
Jeon Bo-ram               born March 22, 1986          She, better known mononymously as Boram, is a South Korean singer and actress. She is best known as a member of the South Korean girl group T-ara. Taylor Alison Swift (born December 13, 1989): She is an American singer-songwriter. One of the leading contemporary recording artists, she is known for narrative songs about her personal life, which have received widespread media coverage.
Taylor Alison Swift       born December 13, 1989       She is an American singer-songwriter. One of the leading contemporary recording artists, she is known for narrative songs about her personal life, which have received widespread media coverage.
Nickolas Gene Carter      born January 28, 1980        He is an American musician and actor. He is best known as a member of the pop group the Backstreet Boys. As of 2015, Carter has released three solo albums, Now or Never, I'm Taking Off and All American during breaks between Backstreet Boys schedules, and a collaboration with Jordan Knight titled Nick & Knight. He has made occasional television appearances and starred in his own reality shows, House of Carters and I (Heart) Nick Carter. He gained fame in the mid 1990s and early 2000s as a teen idol. He is also the older brother of singer Aaron Carter and the late Leslie Carter.
Clyde Jackson Browne      born October 9, 1948         He is an American singer-songwriter, and musician who has sold over 18 million albums in the United States. Coming to prominence in the 1970s, Browne has written and recorded songs such as These Days, The Pretender, Running on Empty, Lawyers in Love, Doctor My Eyes, Take It Easy, and For a Rocker. In 2004, he was inducted into the Rock and Roll Hall of Fame in Cleveland, Ohio, and given an honorary doctorate of music by Occidental College in Los Angeles, California.
```

I try to this but couldn't solve the problem.

```
cbind(do.call(rbind, strsplit(text, ":")), sub(".*[ ]", "", text))
```

Comment: Some steps you've already taken and have not worked wld be helpful to add since this generally isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Regular expressions? `(.*?)\((born.*?)\):(.*)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are the way to go here provided you either guarantee the patterns won't change *or* you make a more adaptable regex if they do.

```
library(stringi)
library(purrr)

text <- "Jeon Bo-ram (born March 22, 1986):She, better known mononymously as Boram, is a South Korean singer and actress. She is best known as a member of the South Korean girl group T-ara. Taylor Alison Swift (born December 13, 1989): She is an American singer-songwriter. One of the leading contemporary recording artists, she is known for narrative songs about her personal life, which have received widespread media coverage. Nickolas Gene Carter (born January 28, 1980): He is an American musician and actor. He is best known as a member of the pop group the Backstreet Boys. As of 2015, Carter has released three solo albums, Now or Never, I'm Taking Off and All American during breaks between Backstreet Boys schedules, and a collaboration with Jordan Knight titled Nick & Knight. He has made occasional television appearances and starred in his own reality shows, House of Carters and I (Heart) Nick Carter. He gained fame in the mid 1990s and early 2000s as a teen idol. He is also the older brother of singer Aaron Carter and the late Leslie Carter. Clyde Jackson Browne (born October 9, 1948): He is an American singer-songwriter, and musician who has sold over 18 million albums in the United States. Coming to prominence in the 1970s, Browne has written and recorded songs such as These Days, The Pretender, Running on Empty, Lawyers in Love, Doctor My Eyes, Take It Easy, and  For a Rocker. In 2004, he was inducted into the Rock and Roll Hall of Fame in Cleveland, Ohio, and given an honorary doctorate of music by Occidental College in Los Angeles, California."
```

Let's massage the blob into something more manageable:

```
stri_replace_all_regex(
  text,
  "([[:alpha:][:space:]\\-]+ \\(born [[:alpha:]]+ [[:digit:]]+, [[:digit:]]+\\):)",
  "\n$1\n"
) %>% 
  stri_split_lines() %>% 
  flatten_chr() %>% 
  discard(`==`, "") %>% 
  stri_trim_both() -> lines
```

`lines` looks like this now:

```
lines
## [1] "Jeon Bo-ram (born March 22, 1986):"    
## [2] "She, better known mononymously as Boram, is a South Korean singer and actress. She is best known as a member of the South Korean girl group T-ara."
## [3] "Taylor Alison Swift (born December 13, 1989):"
## [4] "She is an American singer-songwriter. One of the leading contemporary recording artists, she is known for narrative songs about her personal life, which have received widespread media coverage."
## [5] "Nickolas Gene Carter (born January 28, 1980):"
## [6] "He is an American musician and actor. He is best known as a member of the pop group the Backstreet Boys. As of 2015, Carter has released three solo albums, Now or Never, I'm Taking Off and All American during breaks between Backstreet Boys schedules, and a collaboration with Jordan Knight titled Nick & Knight. He has made occasional television appearances and starred in his own reality shows, House of Carters and I (Heart) Nick Carter. He gained fame in the mid 1990s and early 2000s as a teen idol. He is also the older brother of singer Aaron Carter and the late Leslie Carter."
## [7] "Clyde Jackson Browne (born October 9, 1948):"
## [8] "He is an American singer-songwriter, and musician who has sold over 18 million albums in the United States. Coming to prominence in the 1970s, Browne has written and recorded songs such as These Days, The Pretender, Running on Empty, Lawyers in Love, Doctor My Eyes, Take It Easy, and  For a Rocker. In 2004, he was inducted into the Rock and Roll Hall of Fame in Cleveland, Ohio, and given an honorary doctorate of music by Occidental College in Los Angeles, California."
```

The regex looked for the name and date pattern and split it on either side. This "over-splits" but the `discard()` takes care of the blank lines.

Now we have line pairs of name/dob and the description and can iterate over them using a "by 2" index:

```
starts <- seq(1, length(lines), 2) 
ends <- starts + 1

map2_df(starts, ends, ~{

  stri_split_fixed(lines[.x], "(")[[1]] %>% 
    stri_replace_all_fixed("):", "") %>% 
    stri_replace_all_fixed("born ", "") -> name_dob

  data_frame(
    name = name_dob[1],
    born = name_dob[2],
    detail = lines[.y]
  )

}) -> xdf
```

The first part of the inner block separates & cleans the name/dob. The latter makes a data frame row and `purrr`'s `map2_df()` turns the whole thing into a data frame:

```
glimpse(xdf)
## Observations: 4
## Variables: 3
## $ name   <chr> "Jeon Bo-ram ", "Taylor Alison Swift ", "Nickolas Gene Carter ",...
## $ born   <chr> "March 22, 1986", "December 13, 1989", "January 28, 1980", "Octo...
## $ detail <chr> "She, better known mononymously as Boram, is a South Korean sing...
```

If you're processing a giant blog of text that could result in thousands of rows, using `list()` vs `data_frame()` (the last part of the inner block) will be faster and consume less temporary memory.

Now, it may have been possible to create a single regex to find each triplet and extract them, but I'll let other folks show their l33t regex skills if they are so inclined to create said likely nigh-unreadable beast.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

With regex

```
A <- unlist(strsplit(text, "[(](?=b)|[)]:|(?<=\\.) (?=[^.]+?\\(b)", perl=TRUE))
B <- sapply(A, function(i) trimws(i, "both"))
as.data.frame(matrix(B, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE))
```